# cgroup limit memory usage failed on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I want to limit the memory usage of a process using **cgroup** but failed with error

```
sh: echo: I/O error
```

After creating a test dir in **/sys/fs/cgroup/memory**. I opened two shell, one run `sudo sh -c "echo $$ >> cgroup.procs"` to set the process, the other is to set memory limit.

It seems it's ok to set large memory: `sudo sh -c "echo 25M > memory.limit_in_bytes"` while will fail to set low memmory: `sudo sh -c "echo 2M > memory.limit_in_bytes"`.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: There is only one case when cgroupfs returns `EIO` (I/O error) - not in-place renaming of the control group ([source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d8a5b80568a9cb66810e75b182018e9edb68e8ff/kernel/cgroup/cgroup-v1.c#L866)), and it's pretty unlikely that `echo` does this. Are you sure that steps you described are the only things you do?

Comment: Btw, how this question is related to Docker? The [docker] tag seems useless here.